# Why does an assignment for double-sliced numpy arrays not work?

Tags: python, numpy, variable-assignment, slice

why do the following lines not work as I expect?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,1,2,1,1])
a[a==1][1:] = 3
print a
>>> [0 1 2 1 1]
# I would expect [0 1 2 3 3]
```

Is this a 'bug' or is there another recommended way to this?

On the other hand, the following works:

```
a[a==1] = 3
print a
>>> [0 3 2 3 3]
```

Cheers, Philipp

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It appears you simply can't do an assignment through a double-slice like that.

This works though:

```
a[numpy.where(a==1)[0][1:]] = 3
```

Answer (score 10):

It's related to how fancy indexing works. There is a thorough explanation [here](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2008-January/031101.html). It is done this way to allow inplace modification with fancy indexing (ie `a[x>3] *= 2`). A consequence of this is that you can't assign to a double index as you have found. Fancy indexing always returns a copy rather than a view.

Comment: Actually, your solution modifies the first occurrence of 1, which is not what he wants.

Comment: Right - took it off before your comment. Ps hi Philip it's Robin!

Comment: Hey Robin - what chance is that to meet here... Cheers from munich!

Answer (score 3):

Because the a[a==1] part isn't actually a slice.  It creates a new array. It makes sense when you think about it-- you're only taking the elements that satisfy the boolean condition (like a filter operation).

Comment: I added a second example that works like I expect. I don't really see the difference. Shouldn't the assignment being "piped through"?

Comment: I don't think this is quite right.  If you do `a[a==1] = 3`, that actually changes the contents of a.

Comment: @Dave - I think this is perimosocodiae is correct, and that your counter-example is due to something more like a hack in the numpy internals to create the appearance of an in-place operation.

Comment: @tom10 - It's not a "hack".  It's part of the implementation of the array class.  Behavior is documented, for instance, here:  http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial#head-864862d3f2bb4c32f04260fac61eb4ef34788c4c.  "Slicing an array returns a view of it", i.e. not a copy.

Comment: normal list works that way too -- you can assign to slices (only with iterables) `l = range(10); l[5:] = range(5)`

Comment: @Dave - Certainly, a slice in numpy is a view, but a[a==1] is not a slice and not a view.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want

```
a[2:][a[2:]==1]=3
```

Comment: But that requires knowing in advance that the first occurrence of 1 is at position 1.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the conditions using np.where can be difficult.
I would suggest creating an indexing array independently :

```
a = np.array([0,1,2,1,1])
pos_to_change = np.arange(0,len(a))[a==1][1:]
a[pos_to_change] = 3
print(a)
>>> array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3])
```