# Replacing minimum element in a numpy array subject to a condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I need to replace an element of a numpy array subject to the minimum of another numpy array verifying one condition. See the following minimal example:

```
arr = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
label = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2])
cond = (label == 1)
label[cond][np.argmin(arr[cond])] = 3
```

I would be expecting that label is now

```
 array([0,  0,  3,  1, 2])
```

instead I am getting

```
 array([0,  0,  1,  1, 2])
```

This is a consequence of the known fact that [numpy arrays are not updated with double slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687566/why-does-an-assignment-for-double-sliced-numpy-arrays-not-work).

Anyway, I can't figure out how to rewrite the above code in a simple way. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering [`NumPy's advanced indexing`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) with that *chaining of indexing*, so the assigning doesn't go through. To solve this, one way would be to store the indices corresponding to the mask and then use indexing. Here's the implementation -

```
idx = np.where(cond)[0]
label[idx[arr[idx].argmin()]] = 3
```

Sample run -

```
In [51]: arr = np.array([5, 4, 5, 8, 9])
    ...: label = np.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2])
    ...: cond = (label == 1)
    ...: 

In [52]: idx = np.where(cond)[0]
    ...: label[idx[arr[idx].argmin()]] = 3
    ...: 

In [53]: idx
Out[53]: array([2, 3])

In [54]: label
Out[54]: array([0, 0, 3, 1, 2])
```