# Numpy array Conditional Updating

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have a numpy array.

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [5, 1, 4]])
```

Now I want to update all rows whose first value is 1 to 4.

My code is

```
arr[arr[:,0]==1][:, 0]=4
```

But when I see array. It is not updated

```
In [80]: arr
Out[80]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [5, 1, 4]])
```

Comment: Note that I have many rows whose first value is 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `arr[arr[:,0]==1]` isn't a slice of the array, but a new one as you take exactly only one part. Then the slicing `[:,0]` doesn't apply on `arr` and you don't need modification on it.

Source: [*Why does an assignment for double-sliced numpy arrays not work?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687566/why-does-an-assignment-for-double-sliced-numpy-arrays-not-work)

---

You need one slicing as `arr[arr[:, 0] == 1, 0]`

- first dimension with `arr[:, 0] == 1` that gives a list of indices
- second dimension with `0` : first column

```
arr = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [5, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]])
arr[arr[:, 0] == 1, 0] = 4
print(arr)

[[4 1 1]
 [5 1 4]
 [4 2 3]
 [2 3 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me what does 0 in `==1,0` means? Is it indicating 0th Column i.e First Column?

Comment: @AhmadAnis it's same as your `[:, 0]` which slices in the 2 dimension, `arr[:, 0] == 1` returns a list of indice to slice in first dimension, `0` slice in second dimension ie first column